# Azure Bot Not Forwarding Messages From Teams Channel to Messages Endpoint

Tags: azure, botframework, microsoft-teams, teams-toolkit

I have created a Teams Bot using bot framework and have deployed all the resources in the clients environment. The Web App running the Bot Framework SDK is working and Tested, but when trying to hit the bot through the Teams Channel Link (or through a Teams App) no responses is received and the Web App never logs a hit to the message route.

I have confirmed all the settings are the same in both the clients Bot configuration (and accompanying app registration) as is in our development environment. The Web App works correctly when using the Test in Web Chat provided in the Azure portal and works when testing using a Azure Bot deployed in our dev environment pointed at the Web App in the client's environment. Any tips on how to proceed and get messages flowing from the Teams channel?

I have noticed that there are errors logged in the client's Azure bot "The tenant admin has disabled this bot" that do not appear in our dev environment. I have looked at the logs in web-based Teams and get an 403 error with a response body containing a 209 error indicating "Write Blocked on this Thread". I am hoping someone here knows why this is occurring. I assume it may be an Entra configuration that is blocking the bot? Again, the Web App running the bot is working as expected the only issue is that Teams message will not go through the Bot service only in the Clients environment.

Comment: Are you using MS Teams free service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who comes across this, the issue was resolved by having a tenant admin create a new Azure Bot service and setup the Teams channel on their end. I'm not sure what was happening, but creating the resource from scratch fixed the error.

Answer (score 0):

As per my earlier communication with Microsoft, they have highlighted that ***"This behavior is by design in the new Teams client. unpublished Teams bot app chat windows are disabled in both new and old Teams App"*** While bot services for the team channel link were working in the old Teams or Teams classic ( Recently this was also disabled ), unfortunately, this feature is not supported in the latest Teams client. Consequently, the chat window for such chatbots will be disabled by default so you should publish your app in O365 ( Manage App ). Then only you can do the testing in the Teams App.

**Reference:**

- [MS Bot Chat Window Disabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1463340/ms-bot-chat-window-disabled)